# Node.js forwarding to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, node.js

I want to use both node.js and previously written php code at the same time, so I setup an http proxy in node.js using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and am forwarding the traffic I want Apache to handle to a different port. Unfortunately, I end up with a URL like "http://hydroxic-acid.com:**8080**/bla/".

Is there a way to remove the port so that the above URL would be just "http://hydroxic-acid.com/bla"?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's an article](http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/) on how to run Apache alongside Node. It may be useful to someone.